# Ads in android app, worth it?

Tags: android, ads

I'm currently designing an Android application, which will be published in Play for free. I'm considering including ads, but I'm not sure of whether I should. Is it really worth it to do it? Is the revenue really that high? I don't intend to live off of this, since I already have a full-time job, so I'd like to know how much, approximately, could I expect to earn through ads, in order to decide if I should use them or not.

BTW, I know some people actually HAVE made a lot of money through ads. I'm not interested in special cases, or in apps with thousands upon thousands of downloads, just how much could one expect to earn with a normal app. If someone could post an answer like "Using this library, you can expect a revenue of $X per hour of use of your app", it would be perfect.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: In addition to not being a programming question, this is a question asking for opinion and debate, rather than an actual straightforward answer.  It fails for two reasons.

Comment: It may not be strictly a programming question, but I hardly believe I'm asking for opinion/debate. I'm asking for personal experience of developers who have actually included ads in their applications. Going by the FAQ, I believe this fits into the "software tools commonly used by programmers" category. I may be mistaken, however, so feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience a normal application doesn't make much with ads, only high profile applications or high volume applications will make money with them. I would recommend the [Freemium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) pattern, it brings in the most money.

Comment: Since this has been the only answer in a while, I'm accepting it. Thank you.